# Is Allow: in robots txt an exclusion to an exclusion?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Say I have a MediaWiki website and all the `Special:` namespace webpages are excluded with robots.txt `Disallow: Special:` but there are a few specific `Special:` webpages that I do want to include;

- `Allow:Special:RecentChanges`
- `Allow:Special:RandomPage`
- `Allow:Special:Categories`

**Is Allow: in robots txt an exclusion to an exclusion?**

To ask a more specific and two-factored question: Is the code above what I need to add to robots.txt and is it correct to say that  these allocations are "exclusions to the (general) exclusion"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fair to say that the `Allow` directive is an exclusion from an exclusion, but that's all just semantics; you could also say that it's an "inclusion within an exclusion," or however you want to phrase it.

The point is, it allows you to make an exception for certain documents or folders when you've excluded their otherwise general path from being crawled by compliant spiders.

Your robots.txt will probably look more like this (depending on your URL structure; just make sure you start at the root):

```
# Your robots.txt
User-agent: *
Allow: /Special:RecentChanges
Allow: /Special:RandomPage
Allow: /Special:Categories
Disallow: /Special
```

I placed the `Allow` before `Disallow` - this format ensures that nothing's been disallowed before it could be allowed.

In short just follow the standards ([Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt) and [Yoast](https://yoast.com/ultimate-guide-robots-txt/) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) for reference), as they relate to your website. You have the right idea.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer ; please have a look in [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Robots.txt] ; I understand that they do require `:` in that particular case and that this is not a directory ; please kindly consider to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have suggested this edit (in case it doesn't appear): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69782

Comment: Hi @lahmedi, thank you for the additional info. I made some updates based on that. Please note, I don't know the full scope of your project, so the above robots.txt is just a basic example; you'll have to actually write the file it as you see fit, based on your structure of your actual URL's.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer; I already wrote a robots.txt which I might upload for review in MediaWiki Support Desk and/or in Code Review StackExchange (or both); but before I do that, a few changes might be needed.

Comment: "I put a wildcard after 'Categories,'" - `robots.txt` is prefix-matching anyway, so the `*` at the end of the URL-path is ignored.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite - amended, per your suggestion.